# Extracting coefficients of multinomial cv.glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet, multinomial

How do you extract the coefficients corresponding to a specific `lambda` of a `cv.glmnet` object built on a multinomial model? When I try to do it using the syntax one might use for a binomial model, the `coef` function returns a list of coefficient sparse matrices, rather than a particular sparse matrix.

An example:

```
tempcv <- cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(iris[,-5]), y=iris[,5], family="multinomial", 
                    nfolds=20, alpha=0.5)
coefsMin <- coef(tempcv, s="lambda.min")
```

When I ran this, I got:

```
> coefsMin[[3]]
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                  1
(Intercept)  -19.091925
Sepal.Length   .       
Sepal.Width   -3.755938
Petal.Length   4.355219
Petal.Width    8.909600

> coefsMin[[2]]
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                 1
(Intercept)   4.616488
Sepal.Length  1.649614
Sepal.Width   .       
Petal.Length -1.088160
Petal.Width  -1.884997

> coefsMin[[1]]
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                 1
(Intercept)  14.475437
Sepal.Length -1.843070
Sepal.Width   5.312490
Petal.Length -2.698684
Petal.Width  -5.708280
```

So the entries of the `coefsMin` list can have different coefficient levels and different degrees of sparsity. Do all of the coefficient sets somehow correspond to the same `lambda` value? If so, is there a reason (other than sparsity) to pick one over the other?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I think my issue was forgetting how multinomial regression works. The prediction formula for multinomial regression is

[image]

So you need a set of coefficients for every class.